How to draw rectangle to extract the ROI of a QImage displayed in a Qlabel widget
I've created a AnotherWidget window based on QWidget that contains a Qlabel and some other QLineEdit to show the X and Y Offset, also a Width and Height for the rectangle selection of the image.
The initial condition to met is to draw a rectangle over the image. Showing the image in a QLabel is successful, but when I draw the rectangle, it seems like it draws on the Widget window background. Here are few images to explain the situation.
The widget window that I've been working on:
this image
The current situation when drawing rectangle:
this situation image
The mouse event and painting event were fine, but it draws the rectangle on the background! (Weird, maybe i miss something when working with the Qlabel)
I kinda new with all this PyQt things, and currently using PySide6 in my VSCode environment. here's the code

class AnotherWidget(QWidget, Ui_ROIWidget):
    roi_selected = Signal(int,int,int,int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Custom ROI selection")
        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)

        qp = QPainter(self)
        br = QBrush(QColor(100, 10, 10, 40))  
        qp.setBrush(br)   
        qp.drawRect(QRect(self.begin, self.end))       

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.rect = QRect(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        self.update()
        x, y, width, height = self.rect.x(), self.rect.y(), self.rect.width(), self.rect.height()
        self.roi_selected.emit(x, y, width, height)
        self.update()

    @Slot()
    def show_image(self,image):
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

What happened to this? is there something i miss on my method definition with the QPainter, or i should use another widget instead of Qlabel to display the image? what should i do?
EDIT
assuming it might be needed, im using QtDesigner to adjust all the widget and mainwindow, and here I'm emitting ImageROI as a captured image signal from camera Thread to the main window method.

class CameraProccess(QThread):
    #Signal type definition 
    Image=Signal(QImage)
    ImageProcess = Signal(QImage)
    ImageCaptured = Signal(QImage)
    ImageROI = Signal(QImage)
    
    [...]

class mainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Recorder Inspection Monitor V1.0")
        self.resize(1280,800)

        self.ROIwindow = AnotherWidget()
        self.setROIButton.clicked.connect(self.toggle_roiWindow)
 
    [...]
 
    def toggle_roiWindow(self):
        global setROI

        setROI = True

        if self.ROIwindow.isVisible()==False:
            self.Worker1_Opencv.ImageROI.connect(self.ROIwindow.show_image)
            self.ROIwindow.show()
        
        else:
            self.Worker1_Opencv.ImageROI.connect(self.ROIwindow.show_image)


You're drawing on the window, but widgets are always stacked over their containers, meaning that they are superimposed. You must implement the painting on the label instead, but since you're using Designer you should either use widget promotion and use a custom QLabel, or use an event filter. Note that in toggle_roiWindow you're always connecting to the signal no matter if the window is visible, which is obviously wrong. It's also better to do if not self.ROIwindow.isVisible():.

noted, i'm gonna work on the condition in toggle_roiWindow section. for the widget promotion and a custom QLabel or even using the event filter, @musicamante, is there any "how to" documentation or links that i could find a read?

Just do a google search on site:stackoverflow.com with the related keywords and you'll see plenty of results. Note that you should normally only connect once to a signal. If the user closes the ROIwindow on their own, it will not disconnect automatically, then isVisible() will be False, therefore connecting to the signal once more, which is wrong. You should either create a custom signal that is emitted on closeEvent() of that window (and connect it to a function that disconnect the ImageROI signal), or eventually use the Qt.UniqueConnection argument of connect in a try/except.

No. You should use QRubberBand class instead of paintEvent.
paintEvent draws on the widget itself (Exactly speaking, the widget as paintDevice.)
You put your image on the device, so you can't draw rectangle on the image. You have carelessly been drawing on the widget, so the image hides the rectangle.
Owing to no complete minimal sample code, I submit a demonstration for using QRubberband.
Please delete the codes of paintEvent.
You can get the information about how to use QRubberBand.
Qt Documentation - QRubberBand
PySide6:
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QRubberBand
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QColor, QPixmap
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal, Slot, QPoint, QRect

class AnotherWidget(QWidget ):
    roi_selected = Signal(int,int,int,int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Custom ROI selection")
        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Shape.Rectangle, self)
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
 

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.position().toPoint()
        self.end = event.position().toPoint()
        rect = QRect()
        rect.setCoords(self.begin.x(), self.begin.y(), self.end.x(), self.end.y())
        self.rubberBand .setGeometry(rect)
        self.rubberBand.show()
  
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.position().toPoint()
        rect = QRect()
        rect.setCoords(self.begin.x(), self.begin.y(), self.end.x(), self.end.y())    
        self.rubberBand .setGeometry(rect)
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.position().toPoint()
        self.end = event.position().toPoint()
        rect = QRect()
        rect.setCoords(self.begin.x(), self.begin.y(), self.end.x(), self.end.y())
        self.rubberBand .setGeometry(rect)

        self.update()
        x, y, width, height = rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width(), rect.height()
        self.roi_selected.emit(x, y, width, height)
        self.update()
        self.rubberBand.close()

    @Slot()
    def show_image(self,image):
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

def main():
        import sys
        app = QApplication()
        w = AnotherWidget()
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

